# How Do I Add A File to The 'Directory' Above My Repos?

Tags: github

Can somebody tell me what is the best way to add a file above my repos?
I have five repos as such:

> /home/Peter/repos/

```
-repo1 
-repo2 
-repo3 
-repo4 
-repo5
```

Now, for repo5 I need to have a file in its parent directory such as:

```
-repo1 
-repo2 
-repo3 
-repo4 
-pom.xml 
-repo5
```

Do I need to initialize my repos folder as a repository and then all my
current repositories become sub-repositories to that repository?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git, unlike SVN, is project-centric. In Subversion you can checkout and track any directory, including repository root directory. In Git however project is the only item you can version.

That being said you essentially have a group of projects on GitHub, there is no accessible parent directory where they are located. Based on your description you should probably have just a single repository with `repo1`, `repo2`... subdirectories (these are actually just a maven submodules).

Answer (score 0):

you can't add a file above your repositories root directory.